# Mapping multiple click events to a single method

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently i am faceing a problem while Mapping multiple click events to a single method. My currently
implimentation goes as follows and its working fine but i need a better way to handle multiple buttons
using one method.can any one help with this please.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-draggable',
  templateUrl: './draggable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./draggable.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  status1: boolean = false;
  status2: boolean = false;
  status3: boolean = false;
  status4: boolean = false;
  status5: boolean = false;
  status6: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  clickEvent1() {
    this.status1 = !this.status1;
  }
  clickEvent2() {
    this.status2 = !this.status2;
  }
  clickEvent3() {
    this.status3 = !this.status3;
  }
  clickEvent4() {
    this.status4 = !this.status4;
  }
  clickEvent5() {
    this.status5 = !this.status5;
  }
  clickEvent6() {
    this.status6 = !this.status6;
  }
}
```

Need to reduce amount of method and variable definition inside the ts file and also in the template file. **div tags can be also add dynamically up to max 10 divs**...

app.component.html

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row grid">
          <div class="col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder"
               (click)="clickEvent1()"  
               [ngClass]="status1 ? 'col-md-8 my-3 grid__widget-holder' : 'col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder'">
              <div class="card widget">
                  <div class="card-header widget__header">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Widget 1
                            <button class="float-right" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-bandcamp">
                                    </i>
                                </button>
                      </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body widget__body">
                      Content
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer widget__footer">
                      Footer
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder"
          (click)="clickEvent2()"  
          [ngClass]="status2 ? 'col-md-8 my-3 grid__widget-holder' : 'col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder'">
         <div class="card widget">
                  <div class="card-header widget__header">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Widget 2
                            <button class="float-right" type="button">
                                    <i  class="fa fa-bandcamp">
                                    </i>
                            </button>
                      </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body widget__body">
                      Content
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer widget__footer">
                      Footer
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder"
          (click)="clickEvent3()"  
          [ngClass]="status3 ? 'col-md-8 my-3 grid__widget-holder' : 'col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder'">
         <div class="card widget">
                  <div class="card-header widget__header">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Widget 3
                            <button class="float-right" type="button">
                                    <i  class="fa fa-bandcamp">
                                    </i>
                                </button>
                      </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body widget__body">
                      Content
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer widget__footer">
                      Footer
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder"
          (click)="clickEvent4()"  
          [ngClass]="status4 ? 'col-md-8 my-3 grid__widget-holder' : 'col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder'">
         <div class="card widget">
                  <div class="card-header widget__header">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Widget 4
                            <button class="float-right" type="button">
                                    <i  class="fa fa-bandcamp">
                                    </i>
                                </button>
                      </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body widget__body">
                      Content
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer widget__footer">
                      Footer
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder"
          (click)="clickEvent5()"  
          [ngClass]="status5 ? 'col-md-8 my-3 grid__widget-holder' : 'col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder'">
         <div class="card widget">
                  <div class="card-header widget__header">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Widget 5
                            <button class="float-right" type="button">
                                    <i  class="fa fa-bandcamp">
                                    </i>
                                </button>
                      </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body widget__body">
                      Content
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer widget__footer">
                      Footer
                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder"
          (click)="clickEvent6()"  
          [ngClass]="status6 ? 'col-md-8 my-3 grid__widget-holder' : 'col-md-4 my-3 grid__widget-holder'">
          <div class="card widget">
                      <div class="card-header widget__header">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Widget 6
                          <button class="float-right" type="button">
                              <i  class="fa fa-bandcamp">
                              </i>
                          </button>
                        </h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-body widget__body">
                          Content
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-footer widget__footer">
                          Footer
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you show your html code also

Comment: @harkeshkumar html added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible ways according to me

first: you can directly change the value in html by calling the required variable on click event
ex:-

```
(click)="this.status1 = !this.status1"
```

second: if you want to make function in ts then do like this
ex:-

```
clickEvent(status): boolean {
    return !status;
  }
```

and you can use this function of yours in ts as in html:-

```
(click)="status1 = clickEvent(status1)"
(click)="status2 = clickEvent(status2)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Are the buttons toggle switches? I'm asking because the implementation is like that.

You could use `eval` :

```
clickEvent(id) {
eval(`this.status${id} = !this.status${id};`)
}
```

PS: Notice that the expression in eval is quoted inside ``` |``| ``` and not normal `|''|`.

Comment: Yo, @AravindaMeewalaarachchi, why not use the *ngFor directive to dynamically generate elements. Also, use an array of Boolean type instead of creating a variable every time.

Comment: ...and what template are you talking about? Please elaborate.

Comment: Oh thanx dude..that is a such a great idea...i will look foreword to that....Template means my app.components.html

Comment: If you share your code on stackblitz, I might be able to suggest the required changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a event handler with buttonId as parameter and use switch case. Trigger the event handler in html `(click)="clickEvent(1)"`

.component.html

```
<button `(click)="clickEvent(1)"`>button1</button>
<button `(click)="clickEvent(2)"`>button2</button>
```

.component.ts

```
clickEvent(buttonId : Number){
  switch (buttonId){
    case 1 : {
     this.status1 = !this.status1;
     break;
   }
    case 2 : {
     this.status2 = !this.status2;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sarthak. This approach is nice but need to reduce the number of status variables also...is their any way to set a id for the div and parse it to the clickEvent? and also div tags can be also add dynamically up to max 10 div's

Comment: If the div are dynamic, you can create array for your data model and then in your .component.html , use _*ngFor_ directive to iterate over the array, parse it and change the status or any other data with the help of event handlers passing current index of array to it.